# Create a Data Grid with column rearranging facility in my Xamarin App

Tags: xamarin.forms, datagrid, xamarin.uwp

I want to create a DataGrid in my Xamarin App with column rearranging facility and I don't want to use third party grids and avoid custom renderers.

Comment: You mean drag and drop?

Comment: Yes drag and drop.

Comment: Without  using  custom renderers,your application maybe will have different appearance in iOS,Android and UWP.